# UISlider does not drag iOS

Tags: ios

I am implementing the audio player. But my slider does not drag.

.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *currentTimeSlider;
@property BOOL scrubbing;
```

.m

```
/*
 * Sets the current value of the slider/scrubber
 * to the audio file when slider/scrubber is used
 */
- (IBAction)setCurrentTime:(id)scrubber {
    //if scrubbing update the timestate, call updateTime faster not to wait a second and dont repeat it

    NSLog(@"%@scrubber",@"drag");

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(updateTime:)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:NO];

    [self.audioPlayer setCurrentAudioTime:self.currentTimeSlider.value];
    self.scrubbing = FALSE;
}

/*
 * Sets if the user is scrubbing right now
 * to avoid slider update while dragging the slider
 */
- (IBAction)userIsScrubbing:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"%@",@"slider drag");

    self.scrubbing = TRUE;
}

/*
 * Updates the time label display and
 * the current value of the slider
 * while audio is playing
 */
- (void)updateTime:(NSTimer *)timer {
    //to don't update every second. When scrubber is mouseDown the the slider will not set
    if (!self.scrubbing) {
        //self.currentTimeSlider.value = [self.audioPlayer getCurrentAudioTime];
    }

      NSLog(self.scrubbing ? @"Yes" : @"No");

    if(self.scrubbing)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@ scrubbing",@"sdfs");
    }
    [self.currentTimeSlider addTarget:self
                  action:@selector(sliderDidEndSliding:)
        forControlEvents:(UIControlEventTouchUpInside | UIControlEventTouchUpOutside)];

    long currentPlaybackTime = [self.audioPlayer getCurrentAudioTime];
    self.currentTimeSlider.value = currentPlaybackTime / [self.audioPlayer getAudioDuration];

    self.timeElapsed.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                             [self.audioPlayer timeFormat:[self.audioPlayer getCurrentAudioTime]]];

    self.duration.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                          [self.audioPlayer timeFormat:[self.audioPlayer getAudioDuration] - [self.audioPlayer getCurrentAudioTime]]];
}
```

The slider does not drag even if we drag the slider it moves to the previous position. Any ideas as to why the slider is not dragging.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Hello did u set `continuous` property of the `UISlider` to `YES` . this will get everytime u change the slider value. Put that to `NO` will give the value of the release.

```
[mySlider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

- (IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender {
    NSLog(@"slider value = %f", sender.value);
}
```

Did u handle the slide event?.

AND

where is this method `sliderDidEndSliding` u are calling.